# How can I open a SQL Server 2000 database in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

A friend recently asked me to help him to change an application to allow multiple instances connecting to the same back end database. However, he has very limited understanding toward the inner work of the application or CS in general, and the guy who had developed the application for him has left.

My guess is that it is possible to get it done by making some simple changes to the application's database connection properties. The problem is that I have no idea how the database was set up. A note left by the previous developer mentioned that the database was created in SQL Server 2000. I do not have SQL Server 2000 around though. Is it possible at all to open/migrate the SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2008 Express, and if so, how can I do it? If not, what the reasonable approach for the DB migration?

Thanks a lot for your help!

--Angler Y.

Comment: How big is the database?  SQL Server 2008 Express only supports databases up to 4GB in size.  SQL 2008 R2 Express supports up to 10GB. If that's not an issue, then you should have an upgrade path available.

Comment: @Oleg & TetonSig: The database is only a few MB in size.  SQL Server Express should be just fine for my test.  If clients need to handle a large set of data, they can always purchase a full version I guess.  Thanks.

Comment: then - detach-attach method or backup-restore method are simpliest

Comment: Be aware: once you have the database in SQL Server **2008** - you cannot backup/restore it back to **2000** ....

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for the reminder.  I will keep that in mind.  Actually I will not try the migrate the original database.  Instead, I will migrate a copy for the purpose of testing my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can migrate the database using simple detach-attach method or backup-restore method

**BUT**

if the database size exceeds 4 Gb it woun't work on Sql Express 2008

Comment: Oleg, thanks a lot for your quick response.  It seems that I had made a mistake.  I had thought the copy of the database I have was a copy of the primary database file.  I tried to attach it but failed.  Then after I read your response, I realized that I was not too far away.  This time I tried to create a new database with the same name and restore from the file I have with the option of overwrite.  It worked just fine.  Thanks again for the help.  Sorry that I don't have points to vote you up.  I may do so at a later time.

Comment: @angler.y Since it's your question, you just have to hit the green checkmark to accept the answer.  That's different from voting up.

Comment: But it would work in **SQL Server Express 2008 R2** which has increased the db size limit to **10 GB**

Comment: @marc_s yeah, but the question is all the 2008-express about. Nevertheless - thanks, this may be valuable to owner the question

Comment: @TetonSig, Oleg, and marc_s: Thanks for your kindly help.  In recently months I found that stackoverflow.com was a very nice source of help, although this was my first question here.  Thank all of you for making this happen!
TetonSig: Thanks for the tip.  I just did that :)